# Fibonacci-style matrix expansion

Tags: code-golf, fibonacci, matrix

For each row and then column of a matrix, we can add an extra entry with the sum of the last two entries in that row or column.  For example with the following input matrix:

```
[ 1 1 1 ]
[ 2 3 4 ]
```

The resulting matrix would be:

```
[ 1 1 1 2 ]
[ 2 3 4 7 ]
[ 3 4 5 9 ]
```

Given an input of an integer N and an [X,Y] matrix of size at least 2x2, perform the above expansion N times and output the result.  The resulting matrix will always be of size [X+N,Y+N].

#### Examples:

```
Input:                     Output:

2, [ 0 0 ]                 [ 0 0 0 0 ]
   [ 0 0 ]                 [ 0 0 0 0 ]
                           [ 0 0 0 0 ]
                           [ 0 0 0 0 ]


3, [ 1 1 1 ]               [ 1  1  1  2  3  5 ]
   [ 2 3 4 ]               [ 2  3  4  7 11 18 ]
                           [ 3  4  5  9 14 23 ]
                           [ 5  7  9 16 25 41 ]
                           [ 8 11 14 25 39 64 ]
```

Answer (score 8):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 13 <s>14</s> <s>15</s> <s>16</s> <s>20</s> <s>21</s> bytes

```
2*:"!tP2:Y)sv
```

Thanks @Zgarb for removing 1 byte!

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Mio6IiF0UDI6WSlzdg&input=MwpbMSAxIDE7IDIgMyA0XQ)

```
2*         % implicitly input number N and multiply by 2
:          % create vector [1,2,...,2*N]
"          % for loop: do this 2*N times
  !        %   transpose. Implicitly input matrix in the first iteration
  tP       %   duplicate and flip vertically
  2:       %   vector [1,2]
  Y)       %   pick submatrix formed by the first two rows
  s        %   sum of each column
  v        %   append as a new row
           % end for
           % implicit display
```

Comment: I don't know MATL, but wouldn't it be shorter to loop `2N` times than to loop twice `N` times?

Comment: @Zgarb Of course! How did I miss that? Thanks!!

Comment: Does MATL have a built-in for doubling a number?

Comment: @Zgarb No. You need `2*` (postfix notation). Maybe it should have a one-character built-in, it's used often. Also `2^` (square). But I'm running out of code space :-)

Answer (score 6):

### J, 19 bytes

```
(v"1@v=.,[+&{:}:)^:
```

This defines an adverb, which takes the number on its left, and produces a verb taking the matrix on its right.
For the second example, it gives

```
  3 ((v"1@v=.,[+&{:}:)^:) 2 3 $ 1 1 1 2 3 4
1  1  1  2  3  5
2  3  4  7 11 18
3  4  5  9 14 23
5  7  9 16 25 41
8 11 14 25 39 64
```

### Explanation

```
(v"1@v=.,[+&{:}:)^:  Left argument x, right argument y
(               )^:  Repeat x times:
     v=.               Bind the following verb to v, and apply to y:
         [    }:         y and y-without-last-item
          +&{:           Sum of their last items
        ,                Append that to y
                       (v automatically threads to rows)
 v"1@                  then apply v to columns
```

Answer (score 3):

## K, 23 bytes

```
{x(2({x,+/-2#x}'+)/)/y}
```

In action:

```
  {x(2({x,+/-2#x}'+)/)/y}[3;(1 1 1;2 3 4)]
(1 1 1 2 3 5
 2 3 4 7 11 18
 3 4 5 9 14 23
 5 7 9 16 25 41
 8 11 14 25 39 64)
```

Try it [here](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/index.html?run=%20%7Bx%282%28%7Bx%2C%2B%2F-2%23x%7D'%2B%29%2F%29%2Fy%7D%5B3%3B%281%201%201%3B2%203%204%29%5D).

Comment: it still works if you remove the leading `{x` and trailing `y}`

Answer (score 3):

## Jelly, <s>15</s> <s>13</s> 12 bytes

*-1 byte by @Dennis*

```
ṫ-S;@"Z
ÇḤ}¡
```

Like @LuisMendo's MATL answer, this transposes the array before doing the transformation along one axis. Therefore, we need to call the function 2*n times.

```
ṫ-S;@"Z       Helper link. Input: x (2D array)
 -              Numeric literal: -1
ṫ               Get x[-1:], i.e. last two rows in x
  S             Sum
   ;@"          Append each to x. " is 'zipWith'; @ switches argument order.
      Z         Transpose the array.
ÇḤ}¡          Main link. Input: a, n
Ç               Call the last link on a
 Ḥ}             2n
   ¡            times.
```

Try it [here](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmrLVM7QCJaCsOH4bikfcKh&input=&args=WzEsMSwxXSxbMiwzLDRd+Mw).

Answer (score 2):

### ES6, 134 bytes

```
(n,a)=>[...a.map(b=>[...b,...Array(n)].map(c=>(c<1/0?0:c=a+d,d=a,a=c))),...Array(n)].map(b=>(b?0:b=[...a].map((c,j)=>c+d[j]),d=a,a=b))
```

Explanation:

```
(n,a)=> // arguments n is number to expand, a is original array
    [...
        a.map(b=> // for each row in a
            [...b,...Array(n)] // append n elements to the row
            .map(c=>(c<1/0?0:c=a+d,d=a,a=c))) // scan the elements and fill the new ones by summing the previous two
        ,...Array(n)] // append n rows
    .map(b=>(b?0:b=[...a].map((c,j)=>c+d[j]),d=a,a=b)) // scan the rows and fill the new rows by summing the previous two rows
```

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
q~2*{~_2$.+]z}*p
```

Input format is the matrix first (as a CJam-style 2D array) and the number of iterations afterwards.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~2*%7B~_2%24.%2B%5Dz%7D*p&input=%5B%5B%201%201%201%20%5D%20%5B%202%203%204%20%5D%5D%203)

#### Explanation

Turns out this is the same solution as everyone else's:

```
q~      e# Read and evaluate input.
2*      e# Double the iteration count.
{       e# Run this block that many times...
  ~     e#   Dump all rows on the stack.
  _     e#   Copy the last row.
  2$    e#   Copy the penultimate row.
  .+    e#   Vectorised addition.
  ]     e#   Wrap all rows in a new array.
  z     e#   Transpose such that the next iteration processes the other dimension.
}*
p       e#   Pretty-print.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 67 bytes

```
o%m=m++[o(+)(last m)$last$init m]
(!!).iterate(map(id%).(zipWith%))
```

Usage example:

```
*Main> ( (!!).iterate(map(id%).(zipWith%)) ) [[1,1,1],[2,3,4]] 3
[[1,1,1,2,3,5],[2,3,4,7,11,18],[3,4,5,9,14,23],[5,7,9,16,25,41],[8,11,14,25,39,64]]
```

How it works:

```
(!!).iterate(    ...         )  -- repeatedly apply ... to the first agrument and
                                -- pick the iteration defined by the second arg
                   (zipWith%)   -- for one iteration add a new row and
          map(id%)              -- then a new element at the end of each each row

o%m                             -- add row or element at the end of a row resp.
                                -- argument o is a "modify function"
                                --          m the whole matrix or a row
 m++[    (last m)(last$init m)] -- take m and append the result of combining the
                                -- last and 2nd last element of m
     o(+)                       -- with a modified version of (+)
                                -- modification is none (aka. id) when adding an
                                -- element to the end of a row and
                                -- zipping elementwise (zipWith) when adding a row
```

Comment: I'm a haskell novice.  I've got as far as `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform` and am running the `ghci` REPL which gives me a `Prelude> ` prompt.  When I paste in `o%m=m++[o(+)(last m)$last$init m]` I get `<interactive>:2:4: parse error on input '='`.  Can you give me a little primer either running this from a source file or in the REPL?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: either put the `o%m=...` line (and only this line) in a file called, let's say `fib-matrix.hs`. Then you can use the `:l fib-matrix.hs` command in `ghci` to load the definitions and call the main function just as described in my usage example. -- Or use `let o%m=...  in ( (!!). ... ) [[1,1,1]...] 3`.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: oh, there's a 3rd way: give the main function a name, e.g. add a `f=` in front of the second line: `f=(!!).iterate...`, save both lines in a file and load it via `l: <filename.hs>`. Then you can call `f [[1,1,1],[2,3,4]] 3`, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I would accept this as valid haskell, the top line is a function definition and needs modification for use in the REPL, but the 2nd line can be can only be used in the REPL.

Comment: @DanielHill: there's a [topic on meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7614/what-are-our-rules-about-additional-code-accompanying-function-submissions) which allows unnamed functions that depend on global helper functions.

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously, 20 bytes

```
,,τ"┬`;d@d@X+@q`M"£n
```

Takes input the matrix (as a 2D list), then `N`. Outputs a 2D list.

This version doesn't work on the online interpreter for some reason, but does work with [this pre-challenge commit](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/tree/5a97f8b14b4cf38b5e21bd11fa29359a813ea01b).

A version that works online, for 23 bytes:

```
,τ",┬`;d@d@X+@q`M"nkΣ£ƒ
```

Takes input in the opposite order (`N`, then matrix).

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LM-EIizilKxgO2RAZEBYK0BxYE0ibmvOo8KjxpI&input=MwpbWzEsMSwxXSxbMiwzLDRdXQ)

I will add an explanation after I sleep for a little while. Working around interpreter bugs is never fun.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
u+Rs>2dCGyEQ
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%2BRs%3E2dCGyEQ&input=%5B%5B1%2C+1%2C+1%5D%2C+%5B2%2C+3%2C+4%5D%5D%0A3&debug=0) [Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%2BRs%3E2dCGyEQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5B1%2C+1%2C+1%5D%2C+%5B2%2C+3%2C+4%5D%5D%0A1%0A%5B%5B0%2C+0%5D%2C+%5B0%2C+0%5D%5D%0A2%0A%5B%5B1%2C+1%2C+1%5D%2C+%5B2%2C+3%2C+4%5D%5D%0A3&debug=0&input_size=2)

Uses the same algorithm to most answers. Takes as input the matrix as a 2D array on the first line and `n` on the second line.

#### Explanation

```
u        yEQ     do 2*N times, starting with input matrix:
       CG          transpose
 +R                append to each row:
   s                 sum of
    >2d              last 2 elements of row
```

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab, 60 bytes

I was first messing about with Matlab's fancy indexing methods (i.e., `A(end+1,:)=sum...`) before I figured that in this rare case, simple concatenation is actually cheaper in Matlab. Too bad I had to convert this into an actual function.
Should work with Octave as well.

```
function A=f(A,n)
for i=1:2*n
A=[A;sum(A(end-1:end,:))]';end
```

I suppose this is a prime example of how **not** to make algorithms. For A=2x2, n=1000 this algorithm already takes 5 seconds on my laptop, n=2000 it's almost 50 seconds! (or approximately 30s if A is a `gpuArray` thanks to my trusty Quadro 1000M)

Comment: I don't have a copy of Matlab.  Can I run this under GNU octave?  If so can you give instructions?

Comment: Yes I called it Matlab because it doesn't use any Octave specific functions. Simply put it in a file called f.m and run as e.g. `f([0,1;2,3],1000)`

Comment: I see. 1) save as `f.m`. 2) Start `octave`.  3) Paste `load f.m; f([1,1,1;2,3,4],3)` into the REPL prompt - works for me.

Comment: If you say so! I only use the octave online website so no idea how it should work otherwise. I'll see if I can permalink from there

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 2179 bytes

Just Worked it out:-
This code is on Java Language.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FebonnaciMatrix {
        static Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int x,y;
        System.out.println("For the Array to Work Upon:- ");
        
        System.out.println("Enter the Row:- ");
        int row=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the Column:- ");
        int col=scan.nextInt();
        
        int inpArr[][]=new int[row][col];
        
        System.out.println("Enter the values");
        inpArr=inpValues(row,col);
        
        System.out.println("The Input Array is:- ");
        display(inpArr,row,col);
        
        System.out.println("Input the Array size of Febonacci Array ");
        
        System.out.println("Enter the Row");
        int frow=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the Column");
        int fcol=scan.nextInt();
        
        int febArr[][]=new int[frow][fcol];
        febArr=copyValue(inpArr,febArr,row,col);
        
        for(x=0;x<row;x++)
        {
            for(y=col;y<fcol;y++)
                febArr[x][y]=febArr[x][y-2]+febArr[x][y-1];
        }
        
        for(x=row;x<frow;x++)
        {
            for(y=0;y<fcol;y++)
                febArr[x][y]=febArr[x-2][y]+febArr[x-1][y];
        }
        
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The Febonacci Array:-");
        display(febArr,frow,fcol);
    }
    
    static void display(int[][] arr,int row,int col)
    {
        int x,y;
        for(x=0;x<row;x++)
        {
            for(y=0;y<col;y++)
                System.out.print(arr[x][y]+"\t");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    static int[][] inpValues(int row,int col)
    {
        int arr[][]=new int[row][col];
        int x,y;
        for(x=0;x<row;x++)
        {
            for(y=0;y<col;y++)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter the value:- ");
                arr[x][y]=scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
    
    static int[][] copyValue(int[][] old, int[][] ne, int row,int col)
    {
        int x,y;    
        for(x=0;x<row;x++)
        {
            for(y=0;y<col;y++)
                ne[x][y]=old[x][y];
            
        }
        return ne;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! The question is tagged [tag:code-golf] which means that answers are competing to be written in the shortest amount of code possible (in bytes).  Your answer may well solve the problem, but I see little attempt to "golf" the code (i.e. make it as short as possible).  There are plenty of trivial opportunities to do this with your code, e.g. variables with 1-char names, and removal of unnecessary whitespace.  Beyond that you can [read these tips, specifically for java](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java)

Comment: ... Have a look at the [tag-wiki for code-golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info), especially the **How should I answer a code golf? Any hints?** section.  Also note that java is notoriously hard to golf down to short code, in comparison with many other languages.  This shouldn't dissuade you though - if you have a well-golfed java answer, it is likely to be quite popular, even if it is longer than all the other answers.  Don't be put off by all the mind-bendingly short esolang answers - this community tends to be good at taking language handicaps into account.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma- Thanks... for helping me out as a newbee to this... I'll surely go through the links and come up with a new code...

Comment: Since you're a new user, I took the liberty of editing your answer for better formatting.  In particular a) a clear title stating language and number of bytes, b) code formatting of your code.  On all stackexchange sites, code formatting is easy - simply prefix all your code lines with 4 spaces.  In fact even easier - in the edit box, select your code, then click the `{}` at the top of the edit box - this will automatically do this prefixing.

Comment: Okay... I will just check it out...

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 103 <s>105</s> bytes

```
f=lambda n,L:f(n-1,[l+[sum(l[-2:])]for l in L])if n else L
lambda n,L:zip(*f(n,map(list,zip(*f(n,L)))))
```

Anonymous function takes list of list and passes to recursive function `f`.  Output is transposed and then passed to `f` again, then the output of the second go is re-transposed.  Output is a list of tuples

Saved two bytes thanks to [bakuriu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/5219/bakuriu)

Comment: `n>0` could simply be `n`, since you start with a positive `n` and when you reach `0` its value is false.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 17 bytes

```apl
{⍉⍵,⊢/2+/⍵}⍣2⍣⎕⊢⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQZcjzra0/5XP@rtfNS7VedR1yJ9I219ILP2Ue9iIyAGKgQKAsn/QIX/07getU3UMFAw0AQTXEZc6upcEEFDBSDU1DBSMFYw0eQyBgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>87 73</s>  71 bytes

```perl6
->\c,\m{for ^c {.[+*]=[+] .[*X-1,2]for m;m.push: [map {[+] m[*X-1,2;$_]},m[0].keys]};m}
->\c,\m{for ^c {.[+*]=[+] .[*X-1,2]for m;m[+*]=[m[*-2;*] »+«m[*-1]]};m}
->\c,\m{for ^c {.[+*]=[+] .[*X-1,2]for m;m[+*]=[m[*-2;*]Z+m[*-1;*]]};m}
```

```perl6
-> \c, \m {
  for ^c { # 0 ..^ c

    # each row
    .[+*]                            # new column at the end of row ($_)
          = [+] .[ * X- 1,2 ]        # add up the last two entries in row ($_)
                              for m; # for every row

    # too bad this was longer than the above code
    # m[*;+*]=map *+*,m[*;*-2,*-1]

    # each column
    m[ +* ]                 # add new row
            = [             # make it an Array rather than a List
                m[ *-2; * ] # the second to last row
                »+«         # added columnwise with
                m[ *-1 ]    # the last row
              ]
  };

  m # return the result
}
```

#### Usage:

```perl6
use v6.c;
# give it a lexical name
my &code = ->\c,\m{ … }

my @return = code 3,[[1,1,1],[2,3,4]];

put '[ ', $_».fmt('%2d'), ' ]' for @return;

put '';

put @return.perl ~~ {S:g/' '//};
```

```perl6
[  1  1  1  2  3  5 ]
[  2  3  4  7 11 18 ]
[  3  4  5  9 14 23 ]
[  5  7  9 16 25 41 ]
[  8 11 14 25 39 64 ]

[[1,1,1,2,3,5],[2,3,4,7,11,18],[3,4,5,9,14,23],[5,7,9,16,25,41],[8,11,14,25,39,64]]
```

Comment: Pasting this into `perl6` [gives me some errors](http://pastebin.com/QfYbqyvR).  I'm a perl novice - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I'm sorry I should have written the usage as `my &code = ->\c,\m{ … }` to make it clear that the  `->\c,\m{ … }` needs to be replaced with the code above. I usually use an implicit `$_` or `@_` or explicit placeholder parameters `$^a` because they tend to be shorter. I just didn't think about it. Also make sure that you are using a new enough version ( `$*PERL.compiler.version !before 2015.12` )

Comment: @DigitalTrauma You can also go on the **#perl6** channel on freenode.net and use camelia [(like this)](http://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2016-02-05#i_11997270) to run the code (precede lines with `m: ` and a space) You can also msg camelia directly